# php ZipArchive count number of files inside archive

Tags: php, count, zip

I have this code:

```
$za = new ZipArchive();
$za->open($downloadlink);
echo "Number of files inside Zip = Unknown";
            for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
                $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
                $tounes = array( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL );
                foreach($tounes as $toune) {
                echo $toune;
                }
            }
```

I want to display the number of files inside the archive before displaying the list. How can i do that ?

Comment: For future reference, Google is an awesome tool: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have the answer in your `for` loop:

```
echo "Number of files inside Zip = ".$za->numFiles;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Answer (score 2):

**numFiles** will count **all files and folders** in the archive. If you **only** need the **number of files**, count out the folders by checking the size (folders have size 0):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('archive.zip');
$result_stats = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
    {
    $stat = $zip->statIndex($i);
    if ($stat['size'])
        $result_stats[] = $stat;
    }
echo count($result_stats);
```