# Unzipping to a directory - return

Tags: php, zip

I am unzipping files that are in the same directory to a folder call 'info'

This works fine, and it tells me each file that has been proccessed.

The issue I have is it reporting back to me when there are no files to extract.

This is my code:

```
    <?php

    $files = glob('*.{zip}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($files as $file) {

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('info');
        $zip->close();
        unlink($file);
        echo $file.' extracted sucessfully<br>';
       } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help out to show a message when there are no .zip files in the directory to unzip?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just see if there are any files in there to start with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323367/php-ziparchive-count-number-of-files-inside-archive

Comment: Couldn't you check `if (count($files) == 0)`?

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, so if $zip->numFiles == 0 then no files to extract really, ill give it a go and report back

Comment: seemed to work, ill post my answer just incase anyone else stumbles upon it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$files = glob('*.{zip}', GLOB_BRACE);
if (count($files) == 0) {
    echo 'No files to extract';
} else {

foreach($files as $file) {

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('info');
    $zip->close();
    unlink($file);
    echo $file.' extracted sucessfully<br>';
   } else {
    echo 'failed';
}

}
}
?>
```

This now works, just by checking the amount of zip files in the directory before executing the zip function.